# Java Generics? with identifier exception

Tags: java, generics, abstract

This is a code Snippet from an old exam. Can someone provide me the answer and tell me why.

```
import java.util.*;
abstract class A {
  abstract void tu();
}
class P extends A {
  char c = 'c';
  P(char c){ this.c = c; }
  P(){ new P('p'); }
  public void tu (){ System.out.printf("P.tu->%c\n", c); }
}
class K extends P {
 char c = 'c';
 K(char c){ this.c = c; }
 K(){ new K('k'); }
 public void tu (){ System.out.printf("K.tu->%c\n", c); }
}
 class E extends K {
 char c = 'c';
 E(char c){ this.c = c; }
 E(){ new E('e'); }
 public void tu (){ System.out.printf("E.tu->%c\n", c); }
}
class G extends E {
 char c = 'c';
 G(char c){ this.c = c; }
 G(){ new G('g'); }
 public void tu (){ System.out.printf("G.tu->%c\n", c); }
}

public class Question {

  static void magic( Queue< ? super … > q ){ ← which class is allowed and why?
   q.add( new E('?') );
  }

  public static void main( String[] args ){
    Queue<K> q = new LinkedList<K>();
    magic(q);
    while ( ! q.isEmpty() ) { q.poll().tu(); }
  }
}
```

I copied it in BlueJ and did it like:

```
 static void magic( Queue<? super K > q );
  q.add(new E('?') );
 }
```

but then i get an identifier exception..
Thanks in advance!!! 
Hans

Comment: You have put a semicolon on the first line, which is not correct. Write it like in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Lower Bounded Wildcards: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/lowerBounded.html.

For the question: `which class is allowed and why?` 
The Answer: A, because A is the parent of all theses classes. And we can use it for reference to all of them.

Comment: No, its not working with A, Compiler-Error incompatible types <K> cant convert to java.util.queue<? super A>. With <? super K> its working. but i just can add to Queue<K> LinkedList

Comment: It's work with: Queue<? super A> q = new LinkedList<>();

Comment: @Hansanho This is the question: which class is allowed and why? He tried: Queue<? super K > q, then he got an exception. So for the answer: Queue<? super A> q. Not for class K

Comment: No, you have to call <? super E>, cause E is the lower bound;A lower bounded wildcard is expressed using the wildcard character ('?'), following by the super keyword, followed by its lower bound: <? super ...>.